# TikTokApi throws an error in Flask but works outside of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a strange problem when using flask + TikTok API that I can't figure out.

I have the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
 
tikTokApi = TikTokApi()
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return {'status': 'fail'}, 404
 
class TikTokProfile(Resource):
    def get(self):
        profileResponse = tikTokApi.getUserObject('rosiethepygmygoat')
        return {'user' : profileResponse}
 
class TikTokMedia(Resource):
    def get(self):
        data = tikTokApi.getUserObject('rosiethepygmygoat')

        response = tikTokApi.userPage(data["id"],data["secUid"])
   
        return response
 
api.add_resource(TikTokProfile, '/profile')
api.add_resource(TikTokMedia, '/media')
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I visit `/profile` I get the user object, but when I try to get his user page via the `/media` route I get the following error:

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2021 09:20:45] "GET /media HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 468, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 89, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 583, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\server\norway_group\tokmatic-sass\python\start.py", line 22, in get
    response = tikTokApi.userPage(data["id"],data["secUid"])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\TikTokApi\tiktok.py", line 562, in userPage
    return self.getData(url=api_url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\TikTokApi\tiktok.py", line 159, in getData
    verify_fp, did, signature = self.browser.sign_url(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\TikTokApi\browser.py", line 164, in sign_url
    page = self.create_page()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\TikTokApi\browser.py", line 116, in create_page
    context = self.browser.newContext(**iphone)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api.py", line 6710, in newContext
    self._sync(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_sync_base.py", line 95, in _sync
    self._dispatcher_fiber.switch()
greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread
```

I thought that there is an issue with the TikTokApi package but when I try the same code outside the flask resource:

```
data = tikTokApi.getUserObject('rosiethepygmygoat')
response = tikTokApi.userPage(data["id"],data["secUid"])
print(response)
```

I get the object I need.

So am I missing a specific configuration for flask or something else? Any insights will be much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose it could be helpful to check this thread on github: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/65

Comment: You need to set `debug` to `False`

Answer (score 0):

Run your flask application using this comands:

```
flask run --without-threads
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).